# Is there an Unminified Version of google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to find the unminified version of: https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js.
I'm able to run it through a beautifier, but still is not helping much.

Google provides this unminified version of the tracking snippet: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tracking-snippet-reference
I'm wondering if there's something similar about their analytics code.

Comment: What about this repo? https://github.com/LeZuse/ga-unobfuscated

Comment: @janfitz It is beautified version of js and not unminified.

Comment: Did you find unminified version?

Comment: @Arman I tried to unminified it and convert the part which i needed. So answer to your question is i don't find it anywhere as it is not provided by google :) but yes i unminified part which i needed.